# How-to update 2 table in one query

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-update

I have two table :

`Login` with 4 attributes :

```
 1. NRIC
 2. NAME
 3. PASSWORD
 4. TYPE (USER / ADMIN)
```

`DETAILS` with 4 attributes :

```
 1. NRIC
 2. NAME
 3. PASSWORD
 4. EMAIL
```

I want table `LOGIN` to be UPDATED IF table `DETAILS` were updated.

For an example, if the `password` in table `DETAILS` were updated, supposed table `LOGIN` should be UPDATED too.

```
SQLCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE DETAILS set PASSWORD='" & TextBoxPassword.Text & "',EMAIL='" & TextBoxEmail.Text & "' WHERE NRIC='" & myVar2 & "'"
```

How can i update them both?

Answer (score 3):

Use SqlTransaction for this, below are the reference code:

**C#:**

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("[Your connection string]");
    conn.Open();
    SqlTransaction Trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
    SqlCommand SQLCmd = new SqlCommand("",conn);
    SQLCmd.Transaction = Trans;
    try
    {
        SQLCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE DETAILS set PASSWORD='" & TextBoxPassword.Text & "',EMAIL='" & TextBoxEmail.Text & "' WHERE NRIC='" & myVar2 & "'";
        SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SQLCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Login  set PASSWORD='" & TextBoxPassword.Text & "' WHERE NRIC='" & myVar2 & "'";
        SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Trans.Commit();

    }
    catch
    {
        Trans.Rollback();
    }
    finally {
        conn.Close();

    }
```

**VB:**

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection("[Your connection string]")
conn.Open()
Dim Trans As SqlTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction()
Dim SQLCmd As New SqlCommand("", conn)
SQLCmd.Transaction = Trans
Try
  SQLCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE DETAILS set PASSWORD='" And TextBoxPassword.Text And "',EMAIL='" And TextBoxEmail.Text And "' WHERE NRIC='" And myVar2 And "'"
  SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  SQLCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Login  set PASSWORD='" And TextBoxPassword.Text And "' WHERE NRIC='" And myVar2 And "'"
  SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

  Trans.Commit()
Catch
  Trans.Rollback()
Finally

  conn.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: If you change this to parameterized sql i'll give you a +1.

Answer (score 2):

Update the details table first.
Then commit the changes .
Then update the login table.
Transactions :D

Answer (score 1):

```
MySQL = "DECLARE @NumberOfRowsUpdated INT" & vbcrlf
MySQL &= "" & vbcrlf 
MySQL &= "UPDATE details" & vbcrlf 
MySQL &= "SET password = '@password'," & vbcrlf 
MySQL &= "    email = '@email'" & vbcrlf 
MySQL &= "WHERE NRIC = '@nric'" & vbcrlf 
MySQL &= "" & vbcrlf 
MySQL &= "SELECT @NumberOfRowsUpdated = @@ROWCOUNT" & vbcrlf 
MySQL &= "" & vbcrlf 
MySQL &= "IF @NumberOfRowsUpdated > 0" & vbcrlf 
MySQL &= "BEGIN" & vbcrlf 
MySQL &= "    UPDATE LOGIN" & vbcrlf 
MySQL &= "    SET password = '@password'," & vbcrlf 
MySQL &= "        email = '@email'" & vbcrlf 
MySQL &= "    WHERE NRIC = '@nric'" & vbcrlf 
MySQL &= "END" & vbcrlf 

MySQL = MySQL.Replace("@password",TextBoxPassword.Text).Replace("@email", TextBoxEmail.Text).Replace("@nric", myVar2)

SqlCmd.Commandtext = MySQL
SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

The people who posted answers already with 'Commit and Rollback' solutions are wrong.  Those solutions do not consider that the query executed actually "UPDATED" details.  This solution makes sure that the first query actually "UPDATED" a row in details before doing the second query.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that is more VB than SQL solution:

```
Dim intTotalRowsUpdated As Integer
SQLCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE DETAILS set PASSWORD='" & TextBoxPassword.Text & "',EMAIL='" & TextBoxEmail.Text & "' WHERE NRIC='" & myVar2 & "'"
intTotalRowsUpdated = SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
If intTotalRowsUpdated > 0 Then
    SQLCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE login set PASSWORD='" & TextBoxPassword.Text & "',EMAIL='" & TextBoxEmail.Text & "' WHERE NRIC='" & myVar2 & "'"
    SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Stored Procedure to perform this task.
Something like the below,

```
CREATE PROC proc_UpdateProcedure    
@PASSWORD VARCHAR(100),     
@NRIC INT    
AS    
DECLARE @Ret INT  

BEGIN TRANSACTION    
 BEGIN TRY  
  -- UPDATE DETAILS TABLE  
  UPDATE DETAILS SET PASSWORD = @PASSWORD WHERE NRIC = @NRIC

  -- UPDATE Login TABLE
  UPDATE Login SET PASSWORD = @PASSWORD WHERE NRIC = @NRIC 

  COMMIT TRANSACTION  
  SET @Ret = 1  
  SELECT @Ret  
 END TRY  
 BEGIN CATCH   
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION  
  SET @Ret = 0  
  SELECT @Ret  
 END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are really looking into updating one table whenever another is updated, you might want to consider a trigger:

```
create trigger trigUpdateDetails
on details
after update
as
begin
    update login
    set 
        password=ins.password
    from login td
    join inserted ins on td.nric = ins.nric
end
```

This trigger causes any update of the details table to also update the password field of the login table, whether the update originates from a client application or a statement run at the database level.

More information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164047.aspx

The article is a bit dated, but the information in the article is still relevant.